# JSF failing to load when dependant EJB bean is annotated with @EJB

Tags: java, ejb

The original problem was due to mixing CDI with EJB which is kind of resolved now. But the following is the issue after using EJB annotations in place of Inject..

======================================EDIT - New Information ============

It appears that the JSFServlet is not able to able to find ejb bean, 'tauthenticator' when loading login.xhtml. Also when i look at the jmx beans in Jboss admin console, the name is registered as 'Tauthenticator' instead of 'tauthenticator'. i do not know whether this is an issue as the view requires managed bean 'tauthenticator'

Bean being created

```
21:09:42,602 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder] Binding the following entry in Global JNDI for bean:Tauthenticator
        Tauthenticator/no-interface -> EJB3.1 no-interface view
[org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder] Binding the following entry in Global JNDI for bean:TusersBean
        TusersBean/no-interface -> EJB3.1 no-interface view
```

Partial stack trace when accessing http://localhost:8080/timesheet/login.html :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67)
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.String.toLowerCase(String.java:2496)
javax.naming.NameImpl.toBoolean(NameImpl.java:202)
javax.naming.NameImpl.getBoolean(NameImpl.java:198)
javax.naming.NameImpl.recordNamingConvention(NameImpl.java:231)
javax.naming.NameImpl.<init>(NameImpl.java:254)
javax.naming.NameImpl.<init>(NameImpl.java:291)
javax.naming.CompoundName.<init>(CompoundName.java:168)
javax.naming.CompoundName.clone(CompoundName.java:260)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.composeName(NamingContext.java:1078)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getAbsoluteName(NamingContext.java:1931)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:719)
org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor411.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer$1.invoke(EJBContainer.java:978)
$Proxy459.lookup(Unknown Source)
org.jboss.ejb3.JndiUtil.lookup(JndiUtil.java:44)
```

Extract of Tauthenticator

```
@StatefulTimeout(unit=TimeUnit.MINUTES, value=500) @Stateful
@Named("tauthenticator")  public class Tauthenticator {
@Getter @Setter private String username;
@Getter @Setter private String password;
@Getter @Setter boolean loggedIn = false;   
@Getter @Setter Tusers users = null;
@EJB TusersBean usersBean;
@Inject private Event<ExceptionToCatch> catchEvent;

public String authenticate() {
```

Extract from login.xhtml

```
<h:outputLabel for="username" style="font-weight:bold;">#{' '}Username</h:outputLabel>
<p:inputText id="username" value="#{tauthenticator.username}"/>
<h:outputLabel for="password" style="font-weight:bold;">#{' '}Password</h:outputLabel>
<p:password id="password" value="#{tauthenticator.password}" feedback="false"/>
<h:outputLabel>#{''}</h:outputLabel>
```

Comment: Can you show the bean's code (including imports)?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `CDI` (through the import of `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`) and `EJB` (through `javax.ejb.Stateful`) in the same bean. Moreover, these annotations have totally different scopes, so you should decide which scope to use. And you should decide if you want to use an Enterprise Java Bean or a CDI bean.

Comment: thanks for your answer. From your explanation and a fair read of other documenation, I believe that ejb (as identified by Stateless, Stateful or Singleton) when referenced as a dependency in another class, it is recommended to use '@EJB' than '@Inject'. I tried to use this principle and make changes across classes in my application.  Now when I deploy the application (packaged as war), it deploys fine. Jboss reports the beans marked with ejb annotations are created and registered with JNDI.  But when I launch the UI, I get stackoverflow exception. I will explain with details and code below

Comment: since there is not much characters i could enter here, i will add the details to the original post...